# Excel copy and paste document creating link

Tags: excel, hyperlink, copy, paste

Good evening

I have a document with a rather complicated macro included, mostly just created by recording. It encountered and issue where the macros were in VBA but not appearing. I fixed by repairing the file, however when I try and copy this file anywhere else now, it somehow creates a link to the original document.

It gives a security message when I open the copied document about links. When i check the data tab, there are no links, but if I try and run a macro I get an error message saying it can't open two files with the same name. So, I now cannot move this file out of the archive where it is currently or the macros malfunction.

I'm not clear what is happening, but if anyone experienced something similar your advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ian

No solution tried for this yet as I cannot find anything online.